# Unable login user with Lumen and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

First of all apologize for the basic question but I'm new in both Laravel and Lumen and trying to learn it.

I'm trying to login user using Lumen but I've got errors. What I'm trying to write is

```
if (auth()->attempt(...) { }
```

Tried also another approach like this

```
if (\Auth::attempt(...) { }
```

Both ways the error is

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given

I'm sure also that I validate all the inputs from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you didn't forget to implement the Authenticatable in the model, like:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
```

and Model implements it

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {
   use Authenticatable;
         ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your `User` model extends `Model` instead of `Authenticatable`. Your `User` model should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ....
```